# Liferay and Primefaces Resources caching

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, liferay-6

I developed many Primefaces portlets running in a Liferay enviroment. Since we have many portlets in the same Liferay pages, to avoid that multiple primefaces resources (javascript, css ecc) will be imported in head section, we use liferay-portlet.xml configuration file to import resources.

Now I notice that same resource like dot_clear.gif,jsf.js aren't cached by browser (return code 200) and they takes time to load. Unfortunally I have permormances as primary requirement.
I have configured web.xml to Production stage but with no success:

```
    <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
      <param-value>Production</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.faces.allowTextChildren</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
         <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
       <param-value>-1</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge</param-name>
       <param-value>10800000</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

Should I have to implement a custom ResourceHandler to bypass this or there is some other workaround?

thank you

I'm using PirmeFaces 3.5.23, mojarra 2.1.21 Liferay 6.1.3ga3 and bridge 3.1.3ga4

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue of primefaces resources duplicated in each portlet on a project on Liferay 6.2.

We have solved by changing a Liferay property :

```
layout.parallel.render.enable=false
```

A feature in Liferay Faces Bridge is to detect duplicate resources in the < head > tag and render one. But this does not work with some Liferay installations. Set the property to false fix it.

You can see [this blog](https://www.liferay.com/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/announcement-liferay-faces-3-x-2-x-ga5-released) of Neil Griffin for more details.